# UTF-8 encoding inside database encrypted

Tags: encoding, utf-8, collation, iconv, latin1

i Convert my database from this tutorial

http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Convert_latin1_to_UTF-8_in_MySQL

but i didn't notice the arabic characters **INSIDE** the database is **encrypted** , like

```
Ø§ÙˆÙØ§µ ®ØµØ… „Ù‡ ØÙƒÙ„Ù‚§Ø‡Ø°Ù…Ø§Ø„Ù…Ø´Ù³ÙÙ‹ ÙÙ„...
```

through the php script connect with the database **everything GOOD** , but inside the database the arabic characters looks like that

i try to return the database to the old encoding which is WINDOWS-1256 using iconv by the following command

```
# iconv -f UTF-8 -t WINDOWS-1252 database.sql > database_1252.sql
```

i got this error

iconv: illegal input sequence at position

so i try to run the command again using **-c** option

```
# iconv -c -f UTF-8 -t WINDOWS-1252 database.sql > database_1252.sql
```

it's worked and i can see the arabic characters inside the database as well, but alot of characters missing , for example :

i would like to **go shopping**

after the converting

i would like to

i want to know how could i fix the Arabic Characters to be read as normal inside the database complete not missing anything

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Wait wait .... you say your database was in  WINDOWS-1256 (or WINDOWS-1252?) and you converted it based on tutorial latin1 -> utf8? No wonder the characters are malformed.

I wouldn't trust to the tutorial solution at all. I would recommend that you return to your former version of the database and use mysql `alter table` command to change the encoding.